# Split a file with no more than N chunks but with minimal length

Tags: python, string, split

I have a file and suppose I need to split it in up to N smaller files and the smallest chunk should have at least X bytes and all the files should have (almost) the same size:

So using e.g. a string 'abcdefghij' with N=4 and X=3 will return ['abcd', 'efg', 'hij'] because:

```
3 chunks < 4 chunks
4 chars > 3 chars
```

I wrote a split function, but it sometimes create one extra string so I should probably pass the `x` value instead of calculating there.

```
def split(string, n):
    x = len(string)//n
    return [string[i:i+x] for i in range(0, len(string), x)]
```

The real problem is how to calculate the number of chunks to cut the file with a minimum number of bytes.

```
def calculate(length, max_n, min_x):
    n, x = ...
    return n, x
```

Is there a simple known algorithm to do this kind of action?

**Actually:** the files doesn't need to differ in 1 byte because I want to maximize the number of chunks.

Comment: Your use of `N` isn't consistent. Is it the number of chars or the number of files?

Comment: @gnibbler N is the number of files (chunks). X is the number of bytes (chars)

Comment: But the title says N is the number of chars

Comment: @gnibbler I edited the title. I made it with "string" instead of file in the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def calculate(L, N, X):
    n = min(L//X, N)
    return n, L//n
```

Edit:

```
def spread(seq, N=None, X=1):
    """Yield successive subsequences of seq having at least X elements.

    If N is specified, the number of subsequences yielded will not exceed N.

    The first L % X subsequences yielded (where L = len(seq)) will be longer
    by 1 than the remaining ones.

    >>> list(spread('abcdefghij', 4, 3))
    ['abcd', 'efg', 'hij']
    >>> list(spread('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 4, 7))
    ['abcdefghi', 'jklmnopqr', 'stuvwxyz']

    seq    any object supporting len(...) and slice-indexing
    N      a positive integer (default: L)
    X      a positive integer not greater than L (default: 1)
    """

    # All error-checking code omitted

    L = len(seq)       # length of seq
    assert 0 < X <= L

    if N is None: N = L
    assert 0 < N

    # A total of n subsequences will be yielded, the first r of which will 
    # have length x + 1, and the remaining ones will have length x.

    # if we insist on using calculate()...
    # n, x = calculate(L, N, X)
    # r = L % n

    # ...but this entails separate computations of L//n and L%n; may as well
    # do both with a single divmod(L, n)
    n = min(L//X, N)
    x, r = divmod(L, n)

    start = 0
    stride = x + 1    # stride will revert to x when i == r
    for i in range(n):
        if i == r: stride = x
        finish = start + stride
        yield seq[start:finish]
        start = finish
    assert start == L
```

Comment: I think you're the first to understand the problem. I like that this function finds the right "N" (but not the right "X") so I just have to use the split function written by @JohnGainesJr.

Comment: OK, I fixed a bug in the original implementation of `calculate`.  Maybe this version produces the `x` you want.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean, "cut the file with a minimum number of bytes"? Either you haven't explained the problem fully or there is no unique solution.

As your solution shows, it's a question of division: If `L` is the total length, you can divide it into `n` chunks for *any* `n < L`. The remainder (necessarily less than *n*) 
gives you the number of chunks that will have one more character than the others. E.g., `10 % 3 = 1` so in your example one of the three chunks is longer. But you could divide `10 % 7` (remainder 3), to get seven chunks, of which three are longer (length 2 instead of 1). Or just 10 chunks of length 1, if you are really bent on "maximizing the number of chunks", as you write.

More generally: For any length `m` you specify, choose `N = L // m` and your chunks will have lengths `m` and `m+1` (or just `m`, if `L // m` has no remainder). As I said, it's just a question of division.

Comment: Yes, it has no unique solution because it has an open interval of choice. When that happens, I want the biggest possible number of chunks

Comment: The biggest possible number of chunks is always to split a string of length `L` into `L` chunks of length 1.

Comment: But I don't want the chunks to be that small. Say I want them with at least 10 bytes. So I will have to reduce the number of pieces

Comment: Then you need to define your requirements better. If you want them to be at least 10 bytes, use `N = L // 10` and you've got _exactly_ 10 bytes for the short chunks. See it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about simple or known, but this seems to do the trick.  It returns N strings with extra characters allocated to earlier strings in the set.

```
import itertools as it
s = 'abcdefhijklm'
def hunks(s, n):
    size, extra = divmod(len(s), n)
    i = 0
    extras = it.chain(it.repeat(1, extra), it.repeat(0))
    while i < len(s):
        e = next(extras)
        yield s[i:i + size + e]
        i += size + e
list(hunks(s, 4))
```

Comment: But how can I set the minimal length of each piece. I want to reduce the numbers of pieces if they become too small